# Why i'm getting this output in exception handling in Java

Tags: java, exception, custom-exceptions

Can anybody explain to me what is happening here?
Output I'm getting is

> generic exception caught

```
public class TestingString {
    static void testCode() throws MyOwnException {
        try {
            throw new MyOwnException("test exception");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.print(" generic exception caught ");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            testCode();
        } catch (MyOwnException ex) {
            System.out.print("custom exception handling");
        }
    }

}

class MyOwnException extends Exception {
    public MyOwnException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: You throw it then immediately catch it.  Not sure what you're struggling with.

Comment: The output you are receiving is correct. What output are you expecting and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get the output `custom exception handling`. You have to throw the exception in `testCode` like this

```
public class TestingString {
    static void testCode() throws MyOwnException {
        try {
            throw new MyOwnException("test exception");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.print(" generic exception caught ");
            // throw the exception!
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            testCode();
        } catch (MyOwnException ex) {
           System.out.print("custom exception handling");
        }
    }
}

class MyOwnException extends Exception {
    public MyOwnException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

when you catch the exception you can throw it again. In your original code you are not re-throwing the exception, that is why you only got one message.

Comment: After you've changed the exception catches, the message is no longer `"generic exception caught"`

Answer (score 1):

You throw the `MyOwnException` object in the `testCode()` method, which is caught immediately by `catch (Exception ex)` 
that is the reason why `System.out.print(" generic exception caught ");` is excuted , which finally leads to the output.